# Use of dollar sign in data frames with missing end of the name

Tags: r

Maybe this is not the place to ask this. I recently run into a weird 
error that took hours to debug. Finally I saw that one of the column names
was outputing a wrong value. The issue can be simplified to this simple example.

```r
dframe1 = data.frame(
  hello_a = "a",
  hello_b = "b"
)

dframe1$hello
#> NULL


dframe2 = data.frame(
  hello_a = "a",
  bye_b = "b"
)

dframe2$hello
#> [1] a
#> Levels: a
dframe2$bye
#> [1] b
#> Levels: b
dframe2[,"bye"]
#> Error in `[.data.frame`(dframe2, , "bye"): undefined columns selected
dframe2[,"bye_b"]
#> [1] b
#> Levels: b
```

Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

This is weird to me, is there a way to enforce a "strict" mode for R so this does not happen? I understand data frames are some sort of lists in R but is there some documentation on the use of `$`?

Comment: The strict mode *is* the `[[` syntax you use in your answer. `help("$)` and `help("[[")` point to the same docs, which explain partial matching in detail. Before you get stuck in hours of debugging like you said you did, just check the docs

Comment: I already did, see my answer below. The problem is that when this happens in a complex script, the last thing you end up checking are the manuals of `$` which everybody use everywhere but I am sure a small percentage is aware about this partial matching. I just wanted to point out that. Thanks for the "check the docs noob" comment ; )  . Also my point is that `[[` works with SE and I would like to maintain the NSE-like behavior of the `$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the docs regarding this issue,

> x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]

So if we do

```
dframe2[["bye",exact = FALSE]]
[1] b
Levels: b
```

we get the expected behavior. I still don't know if we can change that behavior without using `[[` which needs string.

### EDIT

As [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363709/use-of-dollar-sign-in-data-frames-with-missing-end-of-the-name/56363710?noredirect=1#comment99331568_56363710) suggests in the comments, this is more or less what I wanted to do.

```r
options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)
options(warn=2)

dframe2 = data.frame(
  hello_a = "a",
  bye_b = "b"
)

dframe2$hello
#> Warning in `$.data.frame`(dframe2, hello): Partial match of 'hello' to
#> 'hello_a' in data frame
#> [1] a
#> Levels: a
```

Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: For future readers, the way to find these docs is `?"$"` or `help("$")`.

Comment: And no, there's nothing in the docs that suggests the partial-matching behavior of `$` can be changed. Though the use case is almost exactly opposite, I think `fortunes::fortune(312)` applies well here: *"'The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like any other magic if used incorrectly is
likely to do the programmatic equivalent of turning yourself into a toad."*

Comment: There's no way to stop partial matching of `$`, but you can warn when it happen: `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)` (if you combine this with `options(warn=2)`, warnings would be promoted to errors